# Sort Algorithm proplem - template

Tags: c++

I have a class of books, and I'm trying to sort out the books in any parameters before printing the books ..

The books are in any container.

When I run the program without the merge line is working normally, but when I leave her, that problem goes:

"| Error: assignment of read-only location '**first .** gnu_cxx :: __ normal_iterator <_Iterator, _Container> :: operator * >> () |

And it brings me to the class : stl_algo.h

Can anyone help me with this!?

```
    operator std::string() const
    {
        int counter = books.size();
        if(counter == 0)
            std::cout << "Empty Book List." ;
         std::string s;
         std::string s1;
         std::stringstream oss1;                                 
         oss1 << counter;
         s1 = "There are " + oss1.str() + " in the list." ;
         std::cout << s1 << "\n";
         /** Sorting the List by the requests **/
         std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), Compare_as_books());
         std::for_each(books.begin(),books.end(), String1(s));
         return s;
    }



class Compare_as_books {
public:
     Compare_as_books() {}
     bool operator() ( const Book* b1, const Book* b2)
    {
      if(b1->getTitle() > b2->getTitle())
            return true;
        if(b1->getTitle() < b2->getTitle())
            return false;
        else
```

.
.
.

}

Comment: Is that the *complete* error, no more in build-log? On what line in your source does it happen?

Comment: in the line of the sort : 
std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), Compare_as_books());

Comment: As a sidenote I would change the design here, make the sort only deal with sorting and make another method for outputting the results.

Comment: can you give the container signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show the definition of `books` but I presume it is a member of whatever class is implementing that `operator std::string`. `std::sort` modifies the sequence being sorted. Because you declared this operator with the `const` qualifier, `this` is const and so are all the members, so `books` cannot be sorted with `std::sort`.

You could:

1. (Not recommended) Remove the `const` from `operator std::string`, but having an implicit conversion which modifies the converted object is going to cause you to write a subtle bug somewhere else, I'd almost guarantee.
2. Copy the contents of `books` into another sequence declared as a local variable. Sort the copy instead.
3. (My choice) Separate out sorting from conversion. Move the sort into a separate function not marked as `const`.
4. Change `books` to another container type which is implicitly sorted, such as `std::set`. This has other implications, of course, butif you want it always sorted this may be the right answer.